# Mock static method in spring boot integration test

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, junit5, spring-boot-test

I have a sample spring boot application and I am writing test cases using `TestRestTemplates`.

We have one static class in `RestController` and we want to mock a static method call. I checked with `Mockito.mockStatic`, but it is not working.

You can find the source code [here](https://github.com/nitin-vavdiya/mock-static-springboot-test-rest-template)

Comment: This could be difficult as Mockito / PowerMock and SpringBootTests are quite different on conceptual level. I would try to mock the `static` call per PowerMock and then integrate PowerMock and SprintBootTest as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39277036/cannot-use-powermockrunner-with-springboottest

Comment: The easiest (and most clean) way of handling this would be to hide the static call in a service, inject the service into the controller and mock that service instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mockito.mockStatic](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#static_mocks) docs state:

> it is possible to mock static method invocations within the current thread

When you're calling `restTemplate.getForEntity("/test", String.class)` you're sending the request within the servlet, which is handled in a separate thread - that's why your static mocking is not working.

A simple explicit call such as: `new SampleController().test()` returns `"test"` as defined in the static mock, so the mechanism **is** actually working.

If you want to test only the method and not the whole request handling, you could use the explicit method calling approach. If you want to verify the whole request handling, the suggestion from the comments seems reasonable (proxying the static call through another class, which could be mocked and injected for testing).

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved by little trick. You should adding a test component that implements OncePerRequestFilter.

Thus, the mock will take place in the thread that executes the business code, and not in the thread that runs the tests.

Example:

1. There is a static method that returns some string:

```java
public class YourUtilClass {
      public static String buildString() {return "original string"}
}
```

2. Create an implementation of OncePerRequestFilter

```java
@TestComponent
public class TestStaticFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    @SneakyThrows
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) {
        try (MockedStatic<YourUtilClass> yourUtilClassMockedStatic = mockStatic(YourUtilClass.class)) {
            yourUtilClassMockedStatic.when(() -> YourUtilClass.buildString(any()))
                .thenReturn("overridden string");
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }
}
```

3. Import your TestStaticFilter into YourTestClass

```java
@Import({
    TestStaticFilter.class
})
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT)
class YourTestClass {
...}
```

4. Enjoy

You can read more about this in the source:
https://maziz88.medium.com/mocking-static-object-with-mockito-in-spring-controller-test-8415c3427091